# Send data to server API that is protected with username and password

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am having a problem. I am building an application that should be built on RESTful API.
I have made all working on my local machine, but now I need to test it on a test server, on the other words, I have to point the application to request data from a test server - `http://www.test.com`.

**The problem is that - the server is protected with username and password** (which I have), but I don't know how to send headers for authorization? That is my question.

I have seen the approaches like this to configure:

```
.config(['$http', function($http) {
       $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + login + ':' +    password);
}])
```

But I don't think that is good. Could anybody help how could I send a data and receive response from a server that has a protection with username and password?

I would like to use something like this easily:

```
 $.get(url, data_to_send, function(data) {
            dataa = data;
        },"json");
```

Or something similar

Comment: Every API works differently so it is impossible to say in what format the auth data should be. Can you give the name of the API you are using? If not I suggest searching for some documentation on it. Auth data tends to be sent either as headers with every call, or on initial request via url query or post body, then a secret key or similar will be passed in the header with subsequent requests.

Comment: Thanks @LcLk for the comments, and as you have +1 on it I tend to agree even more :) Hm, in past 2 hours I have found out that I can use one more server that doesn't require authorization, so I will switch to it without needing to solve this problem, but it quite interesting. I will leave this questions as is, maybe someone could find your comment helpful as you have gave good insights what it is all about.